# is there any simple technique to adjust equal width of these bootstrap elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am new in bootstrap.i design the following html form using bootstrap.
Here is the image given below:
[image]

as you can see,that the right side [red marked] size are not same.
I know about manually adjusting each of the elements width.But it is very tedious.
May be `form-control` causes this.Please help me on this.Thanks

here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Employee Loan Distribution</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">  
  <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script> <!-- bootstrap-datetimepicker requires Moment.js to be loaded first -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format:"DD/MM/YYYY", useCurrent: false });
        });         
 </script>

<style>
#datetimepicker1{
  width:140px;
}

 body {
  background-color: #584F39;
}
.panel.panel-primary {
  border-color: #73AD21;
}
.panel-group .panel .panel-heading {
  background: #73AD21;
}
.form-horizontal .panel.panel-primary {
  border-color: #73AD21;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-group-top {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}
</style>


</head>
<body >

<div class="container"  >  
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
            <div class="panel-heading" >
                <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Employee Loan Distribution</h3>         
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                <form class="form-horizontal" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="acode">Employee ID:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-3" id = "empid" >
                             <div class="input-group">                      
                           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeid"  placeholder="Enter ID">                        
                         </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>              

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Loan Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">                                 
                                  <select  class="form-control " name="month" id="month" onchange="" >
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Loan</option>
                                        <option value="01">Bank Consumer Loan</option>
                                        <option value="02">GPF Loan Adv.</option>
                                        <option value="03">Green Super Market Loan</option>                                     
                                        <option value="05">House Building Loan</option>                                     
                                        <option value="19">Other Loan</option>
                                    </select>     
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="dcode">Description:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-8">
                             <div class="input-group">                                             
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dcode"  placeholder="Enter Loan Description">               
                             </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Amount:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">                                 
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Amount" >        
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Sanction Date:</label>
                           <div class="col-sm-3">
                               <div class="input-group date">
                                   <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span> 
                                   <input type="text"  id='datetimepicker1' class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">     
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Interest Rate:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">                                 
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Rate" >          
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">        
                          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Exit</button> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove input-group class in no use addon-button

```
<div class="container"  >  
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
            <div class="panel-heading" >
                <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Employee Loan Distribution</h3>         
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                <form class="form-horizontal" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="acode">Employee ID:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-9" id = "empid" >
                             <div class="input-group">                      
                           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employeeid"  placeholder="Enter ID">                        
                         </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>              

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Loan Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">


                                <select  class="form-control " name="month" id="month" onchange="" >
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Loan</option>
                                        <option value="01">Bank Consumer Loan</option>
                                        <option value="02">GPF Loan Adv.</option>
                                        <option value="03">Green Super Market Loan</option>                                     
                                        <option value="05">House Building Loan</option>                                     
                                        <option value="19">Other Loan</option>
                                    </select>     
                                </div>
                            </div>      


                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="dcode">Description:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-9">

                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dcode"  placeholder="Enter Loan Description">               

                         </div>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Amount:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">

                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Amount" >        
                                </div>
                            </div>      


                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Sanction Date:</label>
                           <div class="col-sm-9">
                               <div class="input-group date">
                                   <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span> 
                                   <input type="text"  id='datetimepicker1' class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">     
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Interest Rate:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">

                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Rate" >          
                                </div>

                        </div>  

                        <div class="form-group">        
                          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Exit</button> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>    
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gpazs5pt/1/

Comment: thanks @Lalji Tadhani. it is too large filling all the width.is it possible to have equal small size.thanks

Comment: col-sm-9 change to col-sm-5

Comment: thanks @Lalji Tadhani. it worked.also please update your 2nd link https://jsfiddle.net/gpazs5pt/1/ on your reply post.i want to accept it as an answer.Any way can you tell me what makes it equal size, is it grid or any thing else? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

create a custom class like this:

```
.custom
{
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

add this class to all form elements.